# Exporting Maven properties from Ant code

Tags: maven-2, ant

I've embedded the following code within my POM:

```
<plugin name="test">
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <pathconvert targetos="unix" property="project.build.directory.portable">
                  <path location="${project.build.directory}"/>
                </pathconvert>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I then reference `${project.build.directory.portable}` from the `run project` action but it comes back as `null`. Executing `<echo>` within the Ant block shows the correct value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For completeness, the [mentioned feature](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MANTRUN-158) was implemented in the `maven-antrun-plugin` in October 2010.

The configuration parameter you are looking for is [**`exportAntProperties`**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/run-mojo.html#exportAntProperties%20exportAntProperties).

Example of use:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <exec outputproperty="svnversion"
                        executable="svnversion">
                        <arg value=".." />
                    </exec>
                </target>
                <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

*As a side note, at the time of this post (2011-10-20), the official plugin documentation didn't have this option documented. To get the help for 'versionXYZ' of the plugin:*

```
mvn help:describe -Dplugin=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:versionXYZ -Ddetail
```

Comment: Hm, is it really work? I have some troubles according to this [issue](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/exportAntProperties-not-working-in-3-0-4-td5732071.html)

Comment: try to put the exportAntProperties as global configuration and not as the execution configuration

Comment: I noticed that this won't override properties already declared in the POM, but if I don't declare the property my linter (using IntelliJ) complains about the unknown property symbol. Is there a way to tell it to ignore this, or to tell the plugin to override an existing property?

Answer (score 5):

The version 1.7 of the maven-antrun-plugin worked for me to pass a property from ant to maven (and from mvn to ant). Some sample code that calculates an md5 checksum of a file and later stores it into a property that is accessed by mvn at a later time:

```
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>ant-md5</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    <configuration>

<target>
    <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
    <property name="outputDir" value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
    <property name="sourceDir" value="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"/>
    <checksum  file="${sourceDir}/com/blah/db/blah.java" property="blah.md5db"/>
</target>
<exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
```

The property is accessible in later with ${blah.md5db} in a java file.

Answer (score 0):

From the plugin documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html):

Try to add the `maven` prefix, so you have 
`<path location="${maven.project.build.directory}"/>` instead

If that doesn't work, you may need to explictly redefine the property yourself:

```
<property name="maven.project.build.dir" value="${project.build.directory}"/>
<path location="${maven.project.build.directory}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't *think* you can set a property from Ant that will be visible from Maven. You should write a Mojo.

Comment: Put it another way: how would you ensure that ${basedir} contains unix-style slashes even under Windows?

Comment: @Gili I'm not under Windows so I can't test things extensively (sorry, too lazy to start a VM) but I don't think you can. I still don't get why you need this but if it was the case, I would inject the `basedir` property in a Mojo, rewrite it using unix style slashes and expose it under another property.

Comment: Sure but that would require me to write a new mojo. Isn't there an elegant way to do this with the existing plugins?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible from the Ant plugin :(

Comment: Since October 2010 this is possible. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066252/exporting-maven-properties-from-ant-code/7836089#7836089)